# How do I time a C++ program run in terminal on ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to run a c++ code on my terminal and I use from `$c++ file.cpp` and then `$./a.out` and it runs well but I want to know about it's running time and I don't know how can I get that.
would you please help me?

Comment: Try the following: `time ./a.out`

Comment: [https://linuxize.com/post/linux-time-command/](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-time-command/)

Comment: Also can do `/usr/bin/time ./a.out`, depending on taste. Shell has `time` as a built-in command.